# Test service call inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service and directive:

```
angular.module("epcApp", [])
.service("epcData", function($http, $q){
    var urls = {
        load: "some-url",
        save: "some-url"
    };
    this.load = function(){
        return $http.get(urls.load).then(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
    this.save = function(req){
        return $http.get(urls.save, req).then(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
})
.directive("epc", ['epcData', function(epcData){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "some-url",
        link: function(scope, element, args, form){
            scope.collectSelects = function(container){
                // some code
            }

            scope.collectCheckBoxes = function(container){
                // some code
            }

            epcData.load().then(function(data){
                scope.userOptions = 
                // do something with scope.collectCheckBoxes and scope.collectSelects
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And I want to test:

1. *epcData.load* was called from inside the Directive
2. *collectSelects* and *collectCheckboxes* were called inside the promise from *epcData.load*

I can't figure out how to mock the service. This is what I have from what I've seen in the docs:

```
    //Load the EPC main module
    beforeEach(module('epcApp'));

    //Intialize the directive with a mock scope
    beforeEach(function(){
        var element, scope, epcData, $httpBackend, mock;
        mock = {
            load: jasmine.createSpy(),
            save: jasmine.createSpy()
        }
        module(function($provide){
            $provide.service('epcData', mock);
        })
        inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $injector){
            epcData = $injector.get('epcData');
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = angular.element("<epc></epc>");
            element = $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        })
    });

    it("should have loaded data", function(){
        expect(mock.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

I'm getting the following error `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object`

If I remove the `$provide` and `$injector` sections altogether, I get an *'Unexpected request'* error when the actual `epcData.load` method tries to do the http request. So it seems I'm getting close to overriding the service method but I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because you need to pass an constructor function to create an Angular service. You are passing an object.

You can use `value` function instead of `service`

`$provide.value('epcData', mock);`

Or you can create a dummy constructor function.

Also you implementation for jasmine spy should return a promise else the calling function will fail(no `then`). See documentation for jasmine and return `$q.when()` from your dummy functions.

Comment: I actually tried doing `value` but I get the other error, basically my origin 'load' method fires, tries to load the original URL and get 'Unexpected request'. So in that case it seems that I'm not being able to override my original methods. I'll look into the docs for spies like you recommend. Thanks.

Comment: If you use value the origin load method should not fire, as it has been shadowed by this value service.